# Face alignment megaface

Tags: python, deep-learning, face-recognition, facial-identification

i was looking into face recognition and i came across this method to face transform using similarity transform to align faces detected by mtcnn for the megaface dataset, in that the source matrix being used was

```
src = np.array([                                                                                                                                                                     
 [30.2946, 51.6963],                                                                                                                                                                
 [65.5318, 51.5014],                                                                                                                                                                
 [48.0252, 71.7366],                                                                                                                                                                
 [33.5493, 92.3655],                                                                                                                                                                
 [62.7299, 92.2041] ], dtype=np.float32 )
```

can anyone tell me from where do we derive this matrix? and/or why this is used?

reference: https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/29515986

Comment: Isn't there any English source to read?

Comment: i just used chromes google translate that converts it to english, i can refer you to a code file that helps, https://github.com/deepinsight/insightface/blob/master/src/align/align_facescrub.py

Comment: i have seen multiple instances use this src matrix, i know that these are landmarks, but why do they get used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, basically, the points are the landmark points of a face that resides in a  112,96 image, the nose is centered in the image and thus transforming landmark points of another face onto these points will center align a face just like these template landmark points

Comment: How are you concluding nose is always at the center of the image after transformation?

Comment: This is because we have a predicted set of points, the points are given to us by MTCNN, we transform and warp these points onto the above-mentioned src points on a 112x96 image, this centers the face of the image, by mapping the nose of the original face to the nose(center) of the target image